# AAD: Not receiving password expiration notification

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've set up the notification in AAD cmdlet and also the office portal, referencing [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-the-password-expiration-policy-for-your-organization-0f54736f-eb22-414c-8273-498a0918678f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), for my AAD tenant, but no email notification was sent when account password is about to expire. I tried setting a valid email address for both "Email" and "Alternate Email" properties in account profile on AAD.

Comment: Could you share the steps you took to set up the expiration notifications? Did you follow any specific instructions?

Comment: Thanks, I added the link I referenced

Answer (score 1):

> but no email notification was sent when account password is about to
>   expire.

For now, we will not receive any notification emails, because the **only** notification that O365 provides is a pop-up in **the Windows Notification area of the Taskbar**. Furthermore, mobile users(i.e. i.e. smartphones and tablets) will not receive any notification.

If you want to sent email when O365 account is about to expire, we can use powershell script to send emails to users. To send emails, we should have a email server, collect the information about `smtpServer` and `emailaddress`.

More information about how to notify office 365 users that passwords will expire, please refer to this [link](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/133073-how-to-notify-office-365-users-that-passwords-will-expire).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: For now, Azure AD does not support send email notification when account password is about to expire. You could give your feedback to this link, all of the feedback you share in this link will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

Comment: Wait, so Azure AD does not support sending email notifications? What's the point of telling people it does when it doesn't?

Comment: Important things you need to know about the password expiration feature
Here are some things to know about how this feature currently works as of January 2018:

Bug: We're currently investigating a bug that's preventing this feature from working consistently. Your users may not get a notification before their password expires. This means when they sign in to Office 365 and their password has expired, they'll be prompted to change their password at that time without any advance notice.

That's from the link in OPs post.